# Imagick php wamp server -none supported formats

Tags: php, wamp, imagick

After tons of tutorials around internet I'm out, none seemed to work.
My steps:

**Step 1) Gather information about my wamp**

- Architecture: x64(64-bit)
- PHP-version: 5.6.25
- PHP Extension Build: TS, MSVC11

**Step 2) Download Binary**

[Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

ImageMagick-7.0.3-5-Q16-x64-dll.exe

**Step 3) Install Binary**

C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16

additional tasks:

- Create a deskop icon
- Add application directory to your system path
- Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert)

**Step 4) Download PHP extension**

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.4.3rc1/

file: php_imagick-3.4.3rc1-5.6-ts-vc11-x64.zip

**Step 5) Extract PHP Extension**

C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext\php_imagick.dll

**Step 6) Activate PHP extension**

[image]

**Step 7) Restart your PC**

Done

**Step 8) desperation**

http://localhost//index.php?phpinfo=1

[image]

**Question**: Please, how to setup formats?

Comment: phpinfo is reporting v.6.9.3, and your download shows 7.0.3. did you check the php error log to see if your new module loaded properly?

Comment: @MarcB, checked: [01-Nov-2016 14:34:46 UTC] No error - Only to create the file

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Imagick doen't see IM librarires... You can try the solution from php.net:
http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.setup.php#119083

Comment: Nope, I was try it before.

Comment: @MrFreeman555, you may also try to install Imagick from: [here](http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/)

Comment: the same story :/